# Upgrading target framework of multiple solutions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

Is there any way to upgrade target framework (e.g. 4.5.2 to 4.6.1) without manually opening each solution and converting the target framework?
I have come across an extension [Target Framework Migrator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/47bded90-80d8-42af-bc35-4736fdd8cd13) which eases the pain a bit and upgrades multiple projects present in a solution but
I want to upgrade multiple solutions (around 100) which contains more than 250 projects, thus was trying to find a way to automate this activity.